# Notepad++ Regular Expression Find and Replace 2 characters from line except it starts with

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I am new into Regular Expression and I have this problem here.

I need to replace some data in a multple lines which are seperated by commas. But it should skip the lines which starts with `Style: sign`.

Example:

These are the meanings for the data (which are seperated by commas, just to show what it stands for) .

```
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
```

The things which have to be replaced are: `Bold` (to 0) and `ScaleX` (to 85)

This is the whole block of text which need to have some things replaced.

```
Style: main,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: italics,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H004E2C2A,&H00000000,-1,-1,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: sign_1330_2_K_a_t_a_g_i_r_i_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,17,1,3,0,8,30,375,80,1
Style: sign_1446_5_K_a_g_a_r_i___A_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00F1FBE9,&H000000FF,&H004F963D,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-15,1,3,0,2,335,30,100,1
Style: sign_2051_16_M_a_t_s_u_o___M_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,7,1,3,0,8,162,468,64,1
Style: sign_2163_16_Schleich,Times New Roman,16,&H0021110C,&H000000FF,&H007D594A,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-10,1,3,0,8,67,507,25,1
```

and this should be the result:

```
Style: main,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,85,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: italics,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H004E2C2A,&H00000000,0,-1,0,0,85,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: sign_1330_2_K_a_t_a_g_i_r_i_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,17,1,3,0,8,30,375,80,1
Style: sign_1446_5_K_a_g_a_r_i___A_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00F1FBE9,&H000000FF,&H004F963D,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-15,1,3,0,2,335,30,100,1
Style: sign_2051_16_M_a_t_s_u_o___M_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,7,1,3,0,8,162,468,64,1
Style: sign_2163_16_Schleich,Times New Roman,16,&H0021110C,&H000000FF,&H007D594A,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-10,1,3,0,8,67,507,25,1
```

The lines which start with `Style: sign` should stay untouched like I wrote before. Also it can be done in two or more commands. It doesn't have to be a one-liner.

Could anyone help me here?

Comment: I don't really get the difference between the input and output. Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1388978/edit) and add more input lines, mixed of modifiable and non modifiable, (properly formatted) and expected result (properly formatted)

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: Okay, this should be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Style:\h+(?:(?!sign)[^,]+,){7}\K-?\d+((?:,[^,]+){3}),-?\d+`
- Replace with: `0$1,85`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  Style:        # literally
  \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (?:           # start non capture group
    (?!         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't
      sign      # literally
    )           # end lookahead
    [^,]+       # 1 or more non comma
    ,           # 1 comma
  ){7}          # end group, must appear 7 times
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  -?            # optional minus sign
  \d+           # 1 or more digits
  (             # start group 1
    (?:         # start non capture group
      ,         # 1 comma
      [^,]+     # 1 or more non comma
    ){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
  )             # end group 1
  ,             # 1 comma
  -?            # optional minus sign
  \d+           # 1 or more digits
```

**Replacement:**

```
0           # zero
$1          # content of group 1
,           # a comma
85          # 85
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Style: main,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,85,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: italics,Arial,23,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H004E2C2A,&H00000000,0,-1,0,0,85,100,0,0,1,1.35,0,2,10,10,20,1
Style: sign_1330_2_K_a_t_a_g_i_r_i_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,17,1,3,0,8,30,375,80,1
Style: sign_1446_5_K_a_g_a_r_i___A_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00F1FBE9,&H000000FF,&H004F963D,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-15,1,3,0,2,335,30,100,1
Style: sign_2051_16_M_a_t_s_u_o___M_,Trebuchet MS,12,&H00C1D8BF,&H000000FF,&H004D973B,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,7,1,3,0,8,162,468,64,1
Style: sign_2163_16_Schleich,Times New Roman,16,&H0021110C,&H000000FF,&H007D594A,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,-10,1,3,0,8,67,507,25,1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! Also thanks for the explanation!^^

Comment: @TammysHead: You're welcome, glad it helps.